# Bug reporting upload script

Tags: delphi, madexcept

I am using the php script that can be found here http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=26188 to report errors with mad except in my application.

When I manually access the url I receive an empty mail so I guess it's fine but I've put the same url into madExcept and I don't receive any thing .

The upload box doesn't show up any error .

Does somebody has experience with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a php pro, but I think if you move the last brace of the "if isset" from line 55 to the end it will skip the mailing.

In other words, the last if mailer -> send (line 66) is being run no matter what.

If that doesn't work, I have a php script that takes Eurekalog uploads via http and zips them and then emails them. I have an example script I can upload. It is well commented and such, you can probably modify it for madshi: http://jambog.com/elogsample/bugreport.zip

Comment: I originally was going to upload it later, which is why I typed "I have an example script I can upload" but then I decided to include it, the link to the sample php file is at the end of my first comment.